# J2ME applet - run Java in a mobile's web browser

Tags: java, mobile, browser, java-me, mobile-browser

I'm looking to embed a J2ME application as an applet in a web page to be accessed via a mobile phone web browser. Every major web browser supports the embedding of Java applets - does an analog exist for cell phone web browsers?

If not, does there exist a cross-platform way of launching a J2ME application from a mobile web browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

J2ME doesn't support applets, and you install it onto the device in an application-specific way. You can't launch it from a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely out of luck.  The best that you'll be able to do is provide a link to the .jar file.

You could, of course, run J2ME applets with normal browsers using http://www.microemu.org/ microemulator, but that won't work on the mobile device's browser.